# How to configure ssl with azure application gateway?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I have to configure my Microsoft Azure server like below scenario

[image]

So it is like a request comes with a public IP which represents application gateway having SSL and the request passes from app gateway to the load balancer.

LB just forward to the virtual machine(having SSL) on the basis of the port number.

Here there is only one public IP and virtual machine selected according to the port.

I made the configuration but the only thing I am missing that is SSL configuration with Application gateway and same SSL in a virtual machine.

I don't know my configure pattern is right or wrong please suggest me if you have a good option.

My goal is to achieve the request (with the public IP) passes from the application gateway having SSL to the virtual machine also having the same SSL on the basis of ports with the same public IP, Is there any better option than my configuration pattern?

Please help me, How to achieve it.

Comment: In this case, how do you set the backend pool, target the public LB IP? If so, how the app GW route to each backend based on the port number?

Comment: Hi @Nancy Xiong I wrote the backend pool in App GW for the LB(internal IP) and then that LB route the request according to the port, I have updated the question please correct me, if the pattern is not right according to my requirement

Comment: Do you want SSL termination or end to end SSL? SSL termination at the gateway, after which traffic typically flows unencrypted to the backend servers. refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview

Comment: I want end to end SSL, first SSL at application gateway then at the vm end

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/end-to-end-ssl-portal)? If you target VMs instead of ILB. You also could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430959/application-gateway-routing-urls-to-custom-ports) to route request based on a custom port.

Comment: Any update on your side? Is the reply below helpful?

Comment: @Nancy Xiong I really appreciate your quick response towards my issue, I have tried the marked answer and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Settings in Application Gateway and you don't need ILB in-front of your VM.

1. Create a Application gateway. Create 3 Multi-site Listener. Upload Certificates and enter Host Name and the respective ports.
2. Create 3 Backend Pool and add your VMs to it.
3. Create 3 HTTP Settings. Upload authentication certificates and configure respective ports. Create and attach Health Probes to HTTP Settings.
4. Create rules where you link corresponding listeners with HTTP Settings and backend pool.
5. Check if the Health Probes are healthy. If yes, then your setup is complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @msrini-MSIT, it worked and I have finally set up the Azure environment (y)

Answer (score 1):

In Application Gateway you can achieve end to end SSL and you can create multiple HTTP Settings with different SSL port to achieve this without ILB.

If that is the case you will not get the High Availability as you only have one VM for each SSL port.

Can you explain why you need to use different SSL port for each Machine? Are you hosting multiple Site?

If yes, you can easily achieve with Application Gateway. Please let me know your entire setup and if you have any follow up questions. I am here to help you.

Comment: Hi, My current environment is like I have a single site with 3 VM(web, DB) with a different port, LB forwards request to VM(having SSL) according to port, Now I decided to add App Gateway in that where there should be `end to end SSL` means App Gateway and VM should have SSL. So i am confused how to do should I use App Gateway in front of Current scenario or remove LB level and just add VM inside App Gateway.

Comment: If you are running 3 VM with different ports then Load balancing cannot be done. You can directly use External Load balancer with Inbound NAT rule to achieve the same.

Comment: Currently, I am using external LB only for the port forwarding this was the aim. I did not add app gate but I need to add app gateway for that I can remove current external LB if app gateway can do the same thing(port forwarding) for my case otherwise I have to add app gateway in front of external LB and converting it into internal LB and then the first request will pass from app gateway then to internal LB and it will do the port-based routing.